# Calculating cumulative probability from MGF

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Question:Find the probability $P(X > 1.5)$ if X has moment generating function $M_X(t) = \frac {1}{1-t/2}(\frac{1}3 + \frac{2}3e^t)^4$.

I'm guessing I should let $X_1$ and $X_2$ be gamma and binomial independent random variables and set X:= $X_1+X_2$ and solve for $1-P(X \leq 1.5)$. However, I'm not sure how I should go about getting the CDF of discrete and continuous random variables.

Thanks everyone in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have presumably identified that the MGF is for $X=X_1 + X_2$ where $X_1 \sim \text{Expon}(2)$ and $X_2 \sim \text{Binom}(4, 2/3)$ are independent.

You don't need to find the CDF; you are only asked to compute $P(X > 1.5)$. Because of independence, this is easily done by casework on $X_2$.

$$P(X_1 + X_2 > 1.5) = P(X_1 > 1.5) P(X_2=0) + P(X_1 > 0.5) P(X_2 = 1) + P(X_2 \ge 2).$$